# How is the comment/chat @ auto-complete implemented?

Tags: discussion, chat, comment-replies, autocomplete

It's easy to see in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) that this isn't server based, so I'm guessing that this is some sort of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) wizardry.

Specifically:

- Detection of *when* auto-complete should pop up
- Determining the list of items that *can be* auto-completed and displaying them
- Finishing auto-complete (whether it be because it's no longer applicable, or an item was inserted)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an event handler that fires for key and click events, and checks whether the cursor is currently on a word that's preceded by an "@". If so, there's your first bullet point; if not, there's the third (note that even when an item was inserted, the cursor is still on the word, and the auto-completer is still there; otherwise you couldn't tab-cycle through the several users all starting with the same letter(s) you typed).

Regarding your second point: The chat JavaScript has a list of users it knows about, and chooses from them; the Q&A JavaScript just picks the usernames from the displayed comments. In fact, the comment auto-completer could almost 100% be implemented as a user script (and there actually was such a script, and I assume it did pretty much the same thing).

Comment: Many thanks.  I thought it was something along these lines; it's easy to figure out what the list should be, but the logic for when to pop up/etc is helpful, thank you.