# Couple of chat questions

Tags: support, chat

I sometimes see a dialog, I forget the exact wording but it's something like "please avoid extended discussion in comments" and there is a really handy link to create a chat room and move discussion into chat.  It's to reduce noise on the original post.

A few kind-of related questions:

1. Can I somehow trigger this dialog to appear manually, so that I can create the chat room when I want rather than when the system detects/suggests so?  If not, what is an equivalent workaround.
2. If I create the chat room and mention @another_user like that in the chat, will they still receive a notification?

Comment: Regarding point 1 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing

Comment: Regarding point 2: only if they've been in the chat room before, although there may be some obscure rule that I don't know about that includes anyone involved in the original post (editors, commenters, etc.)

Comment: Eek!  A couple of questions.  Ask as two questions!

Comment: What do you mean by "when I want"? Would you want a higher threshold until it's shown? or a shorter threshold?

Comment: A shorter threshold, I want to trigger it sooner when I know it's going to be a side-discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > Can I somehow trigger this dialog to appear manually?

   No, this is not possible, and there is [already a pending feature request asking to make it possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing).
2. > If I create the chat room and mention @another_user like that in the chat, will they still receive a notification?

   No, as far as I know, a user will be pinged in chat only if one of those is true:

   - The user is currently in the room. (No matter for how long and if he posted anything.)
   - The user is not currently in the room, but visited the room in the last 7 days (even for few seconds then leaving), and posted a message at some point in the room. (No matter when)

   Otherwise, only a diamond moderator  can use something known as "super ping" to cause an instant invitation to be sent to any user, even if he/she never visited the room before.

   You can see whether you can ping a specific user via the auto complete: type `@` followed by the first letter of the user name: if you  see the user name appearing in the auto complete, it means that user will be pinged and get notification, otherwise they won't. (Note that unlike comments, where the auto complete is lacking some cases like editors, the chat auto  complete is final and as far as I know, reliable.)

Answer (score 0):

> If I create the chat room and mention @another_user like that in the chat, will they still receive a notification?

Probably not.

Please see [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276204/166799) to **Invite someone into chat**