# Can I see who invited me to a chat?

Tags: support, chat

I had a chat invitation pop up and I'd like to know who invited me to it. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146569/invite-someone-into-chat

Comment: Just FYI, the system is known to mistakenly invite you into chat rooms if you post messages in one chat room that later get moved into into another room. In this case, what happened is that one or more of your messages got moved into the Trash can room, which resulted in you being invited into that room. Don't know whether this is intentional or not.

Comment: @Sonic I think this is on purpose. When your message is moved, you better know it's moved otherwise you won't find it in the future. It's the same as migration of a question.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou Ah that explains it. Maybe the wording should be different though; instead of it saying 'chat invitation' it could be more clear and say 'message moved' (and maybe also show you which message was moved)?

Comment: Yes that would be a valid request, better be posted as a new question though. :)

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting question.

> I had a chat invitation pop up and I'd like to know who invited me to it. Is this possible?

AFAIK you cannot see which specific user was inviting you to a chat room.

Unless it's a private chatroom that was created as a private chat room for you and that user, I am afraid you cannot determine that.

Though, how would that matter which specific user invited you to participate?

If you can give a good reasoning, you might turn that to a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).