# Is the FAQ for Chat correct?

Tags: support, chat

According to the StackExchange [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq):

> If you need to invite someone to your room, do it from the user's chat profile page or from the user card that pops up when you click on their avatar in a chat room.

Is this information correct?

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see a way to view a user's "chat profile page" from their SE profile.

Also, if you want to invite someone into a chat room, they are not already in the chat room.  Hence they have no avatar in the chat room to which you want to invite them.  That makes it challenging to click on their chat avatar.

Answer (score 6):

Not all users have a chat profile page. To have it, the user should join a chat room first.

AFAIK the user profile on a main site / meta site doesn't include a link to the user's chat profile.

You can find the users that have a chat profile on

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/users
- https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users

Related

- [Invite someone into chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146569/289691)

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like the FAQ is misleading, at best.  I think it also would also greatly benefit from the link you kindly provided.

Comment: There's a link in the moderator tools to a chat profile from a SE profile, but not aside from that.